# how to pass the value which i want to update in my table using the jsf and jpa

Tags: jsf, jpa, managed-bean

In update query, how to pass the value which i want to update in my table using the jsf and jpa

i create the namedquery in my entity class

```
@NamedQuery(name = "Showdetail.updateByShowDetailId", query = "update Showdetail s set s.avail = :avil where s.showdetailId =:showdetailID")
```

now i use it in my bean

```
em.createNamedQuery("Showdetail.updateByShowDetailId").setParameter("showdetailID",13).getResultList();
```

so i don't know how to pass the new value which i want to update in my table.

Comment: What type is field avail in Showdetail table? Also paste code of method in the bean, where you have this line: `em.createNamedQuery("Showdetail.updateByShowDetailId").setParameter("showdetailID",13).getResultList();`

Comment: filed avil is type of integer in the table and ya i use the derby database.and    `List<Showdetail> sd =
em.createNamedQuery("Showdetail.updateByShowDetailId")
.setParameter("showdetailid", sdid)`
.getResultList();

Answer (score 1):

Did you try setting avil the same way as setting showdetailID?

```
em.createNamedQuery("Showdetail.updateByShowDetailId")
  .setParameter("avil",100)
  .setParameter("showdetailID",13)
  .getResultList();
```